How to get all http responses from Flutter WebView (in Android)?
I use WebView to load some url (for example this).
And I need to get all http responses (which WebView gets).
I can get response data using shouldInterceptRequest method of flutter_inappwebview package, but for this I must call request myself (for example using http.get(...)), because shouldInterceptRequest method has "request" parameter and does not have "response" parameter.
But how can I get responses which WebView/InAppWebView uses (for not to call all requests second time)?
I need it only for Android.
